# Find the Strings between Start String and End String with just two changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, list, character-encoding

Suppose I have a txt file with strings and I have Start word and end word. I need to find all the words between the start word and end word different by one character.
How can I look for strings different by one character? Do I need to break the string that I read from the file into characters and do a comparison to my Start and End String

Comment: Try a [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find all the words between the start word and end word
>   different by one character; so from the example given my results would
>   be: AAAA, ABZZ and AAZZ.

The task looks simple, but I'm a little puzzled by your example...
I thing you will get next List:

AAAA
ABAA
ABZA
ABZZ
AAZZ

Here is the sample:

```
 private int Differs(string Word1, string Word2) //calculates how much letters differs in 2 words
        {
         //Here should be some checks to prevent index out of range error during cycle
         int result=0;
         for(int i=0;i<Word1.Length;i++) 
         if(Word1[i]!=Word2[i]) result++;
         return result;
        }

 public List<string> ArrangeWords(string StartWord, string EndWord, List<string> Words)
        {
            List<string> ResultWords = new List<string>();
            string CurrentWord = StartWord;
            Words.Remove(StartWord); //removing start and end words from list
            Words.Remove(EndWord);
            ResultWords.Add(StartWord);
            while (Words.Count > 0) //Searching next words and moving them to result list until Source List becomes empty
            {
                List<string> neubourwords = Words.FindAll(x => Differs(CurrentWord, x) == 1);
                if (neubourwords.Count > 0)
                {
                    CurrentWord = neubourwords[0];
                    ResultWords.Add(CurrentWord);
                    Words.Remove(CurrentWord);
                }
                else return null; //wrong source sequence!
            }
            ResultWords.Add(EndWord);
            return ResultWords;
        }


 private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string StartWord = "AAAA";
            string EndWord = "AAZZ";
            List<string> Words = new List<string>() { "ABAA", "AAAA", "ABZA", "ABZZ", "AAZZ" }; //List, loaded from file
            List<string> ArrangedWords=ArrangeWords(StartWord,EndWord,Words);
}
```

In case of increase in complexity of words the task wil be very similiar to DNA sequencing alghorythm using graph (http://veda.cs.uiuc.edu/courses/fa09/cs466/lectures/Lecture9.pdf).

Comment: Hi Anatoly, Thanks for explaining it in a proper way, BUT If you can see the 2nd example i have given : For example, if StartWord = Spin, EndWord = Spot and DictionaryFile file contains:
Spin Spit Spat Spot Span then ResultFile should contain Spin Spit Spot

Two examples of incorrect results: Spin, Span, Spat, Spot (invalid as it takes 3 changes rather than 2) Spin, Spon, Spot (invalid as spon is not a word)
It is clear that the output should have only THREE WORDS 1st is Start word given by user, End word and the one in between them

Comment: Oh...sorry for my inattention.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Theres needs some recursive function to find shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

This is called distance between strings.
Take a look at this:(Levenshtein distance)

http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance